# Kops - Provisioning & Configuration on AWS

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kops

Novice to provisioning resources & configuration for kubernetes setup.

Registered a domain & subdomain with GoDaddy.

Installed kops & kubectl in EC2 instance.

Created a bucket for this cluster to store configuration

I ran below command on AWS EC2 instance:

```
kops create cluster --cloud=aws --zones=us-east-1b  \
—dns-zone=subdomain.domain-aws.com  \
—name=cluster1.subdomain.domain-aws.com --yes
```

---

My understanding is:

1) kops performs provisioning of AWS services(resources) for a two node cluster. VPC, subnets, auto-scaling, EC2(hosting master & nodes) etc...

2) kops creates the configuration file of this provisioning & stores it in KV cluster store of master

3) kops configure *cluster store*, *apiserver*, *controller*, *scheduler* installations in master

4) kops configures *kubelet*, *container engine* & *kube-proxy* on each node.

---

`kubectl` is a client for apiserver, that talks to API server and performs tasks to create PODS, get information about cluster etc..

Questions

1) How does kops remember the state of provisioning & cluster configuration, if I need to later upgrade & configure the cluster? state maintenance...

2) How to view the current cluster provisioning & configuration, done by kops? as a configuration file..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) kops performs provisioning of AWS services(resources) for a two node cluster. VPC, subnets, auto-scaling, EC2(hosting master & nodes) etc...

This is generally correct. A couple points: it doesn't have to be a two node cluster, for instance you can specify the desired number of nodes with the `--node-count`; also, it doesn't directly create any EC2 VMs for you, it creates autoscaling groups (ASGs) and those ASGs are "responsible" for creating and maintaining the desired number of master and worker VMs.

> 2) kops creates the configuration file of this provisioning & stores it in KV cluster store of master

Unless this behaviour has changed recently, no, the configuration settings are stored in bucket you created to store configuration. See [these docs](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/state.md).

> 3) kops configure cluster store, apiserver, controller, scheduler installations in master
>
> 4) kops configures kubelet, container engine & kube-proxy on each node.

As above, unless this changed recently, kops does not install the cluster store on the master. It does configure apiserver and scheduler installations on the master nodes. You can see more of what gets installed on masters and workers, and how these are installed, in [these docs](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/boot-sequence.md)

Based on those docs, looks like the masters have the following:

- kube-apiserver
- kube-controller-manager (which runs miscellaneous controllers)
- kube-scheduler (which assigns pods to nodes)
- etcd
- dns-controller

and on workers:

- kube-proxy (which configures iptables so that the k8s-network will work)
- kubelet
- Docker

and perhaps Docker can be swapped out for other container engines?

> kubectl is a client for apiserver, that talks to API server and performs tasks to create PODS, get information about cluster etc..

Yes.

> 1) How does kops remember the state of provisioning & cluster configuration, if I need to later upgrade & configure the cluster? state maintenance...

That is stored in the "state store" which is typically an S3 bucket, like the one you said you provisioned to store configuration. You can look at the kops docs for how to do things like perform upgrades, change configuration, scale up the Kubernetes cluster, etc. You don't need to edit the files in the buckets directly, kops has commands for most of those operations.

> 2) How to view the current cluster provisioning & configuration, done by kops? as a configuration file..

[These docs](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/cli/kops_get.md#examples) have some info.  For example, you could run:

```
kops get cluster1.subdomain.domain-aws.com
```

In general, I think searching and reading the docs would be very helpful for you in answering these questions and future questions you may have in understanding and using kops.

Comment: YES I created `KOPS_STATE_STORE`. Does it have both provisioning & configuration mgmt data? so that when you upgrade 2 node cluster to 4 node, it remembers the previous state.

Comment: What do you mean by that exactly?  Not sure exactly what you mean by "provisioning and configuration management data," but I would lean towards answering that question with "yes", *BUT* I would lean towards answering your second question with "no."  In other words, when you upgrade from 2 nodes to 4 nodes, it doesn't remember the previous state. If you want to do that, you should back up your `KOPS_STATE_STORE` bucket, or perhaps leverage S3-native versioning features.  Remembering previous state seems like a totally different question though.

Comment: Provisioning data like aws resources & their properties for creation. Configuration mgmt is like installing kubectl, installing container engine

Comment: All the pieces of info (I would call them all configuration) passed to kops is stored in the `KOPS_STATE_STORE`, regardless of whether that info is used to determine things like the number of nodes, the AWS region, the EC2 instances types, or whether they're used to determine how kube-apiserver, dns-controller, kubelet, etc. are configured.  When you change any of these values, the `KOPS_STATE_STORE` stores the new values, kops itself doesn't do anything to "remember" previous values.

Comment: After kops tool update `KOPS_STATE_STORE` via api server......Does controller component in master make sure that desired state (in `KOPS_STATE_STORE`) same as actual state?